# Android - how to overcome the 10 second limit when receiving broadcasts from IntentService?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver, android-intentservice, android-thread

I would like to know, I have an Activity that receives broadcasts from an IntentService that needs to save data and then export it to a CSV file.  However, this can take longer than 10 seconds, and I know there are certain problems with starting AsyncTasks and Threads using BroadcastReceivers that they might get killed after 10 seconds.  I would like to know, how would I overcome this?

EDIT: Note that what I am actually doing is saving data from sensors, calculating data, and then exporting.  Apparently when the app is in the stopped state when receiving the save command from the other app, the app gets stuck in the calculation state.  The save and export use AsyncTasks, but the calculation uses a Thread where I send a message back to the Activity using a Handler.  Does anyone know how I would get around this?  I used PendingResult in the saving portion, but now it gets stuck in the calculation portion.

Comment: I would suggest opening another `AsyncTask` from your `BroadcastReceiver` which will process the data in a separate thread.

Comment: Why not use a Foreground service if your task takes a longer period of time ? Due to its high priority, it won't be killed by the Android system.

Comment: Why isn't the `IntentService` doing this work? Why does the `Activity` need to be involved in saving the data?

Comment: That is because the IntentService is called from another app.  The IntentService is a new addition to my app, and the AsyncTask that saves the data was already there.  Services are a fairly new concept to me, so please let me know what is the best approach for doing all three tasks.  The Thread that calculates data extends a base thread class that is shared with other thread classes, so that is a bit of a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Have it launch a Service to do the work, rather than doing it in the Receiver itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here are different approaches to save data in background.

[Android background processing](https://developer.android.com/guide/background)

It really depends upon your requirements. If exporting to csv can tolerate a little bit  delay, use WorkManager as its battery friendly and automatically uses best approach depending upon API level.

Use foreground service, if you want immediate high priority background execution and you also wanna notify user because foreground services are visible to users via a non-dismissible notification in the notification tray. For example, WhatsApp attachment uploading.

If it is not a very long running background task and you don't expect user to close the app during this, you can use any background execution approach like ASyncTask, Rxjava, kotlin Coroutines.

[background execution evolution](https://medium.com/@elye.project/the-evolution-of-android-network-access-1e199fc6e9a2). A very interesting article to read and compare these different approaches.

Comment: Apparently, I need to compute the data before my export, so I am not sure if a foreground service will work.  Apparently my app is getting stuck when computing the data when the app is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.  As suggested, I used a foreground service, however, there was an issue with my callback to my activity in my background thread that was started by the service that the callback interface was null when the app was paused.  I was able to fix that.

Thank you for your help.